# how to manually install driver in 14.04.5

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I have made a new install of ubuntu 14.04.5 on an old HP Pavillion dv6500, but wifi connection dont works - and the command nm-tools dont show it. Its a Broadcom BCM4311 11b/g Wireless Lan Controler. From the Ubuntu Softwarecenter I have installed the firmware installer for the  b43 and b43legacy driver and the utility for extracting the Broadcom43xx firmware. What to do now? I want to try the b43 driver instead of the not working '802.11 Linux STA wireless driver'. How do I do?

A lot of thanks if somebody answer this question

Pelle Henningsen Denmark

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the Broadcom STA driver, that is, the wrong driver, is already installed. Let's remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and, if the b43 firmware is correctly installed, your wireless should be working. If not, please edit your question to show, from the terminal:

```
dmesg | grep b43
ls /lib/firmware/b43
```